# ipdb *** SyntaxError: multiple statements found while compiling a single statement

Tags: python, debugging, ipython

When using ipython debugger (ipdb), sometimes I just want to paste something in the debugger to see if it works.

This works for single line stuff and loops but if I paste something more that one line, for example:

```
test = 'foo'
test2 = 'bar'
```

I get:

```
*** SyntaxError: multiple statements found while compiling a single statement
```

How to avoid this?